# how to fix this code exception error elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm currently working with elasticsearch, logstash and kibana.

i'm getting an exception that i can't get through.

first here is what i get when i put ip:9200/_cluster/health in my browser ..

```
{
 "cluster_name":"mr-cluster",
 "status":"yellow",
 "timed_out":false,
 "number_of_nodes":1,
 "number_of_data_nodes":1,
 "active_primary_shards":5,
 "active_shards":5,
 "relocating_shards":0,
 "initializing_shards":0,
 "unassigned_shards":5
}
```

Here is what kibana get when trying to request elastic search

```
Remote Address:ip:9200
Request ip:9200/_all/_search
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

It seems okay until now ..

Here is my logstash config file:

```
input {
gelf {
    port => "5000"
}
udp {
    port => "5001"
}
}

output {
file {
    path => "/home/g/stdout.log"
}
elasticsearch {
    cluster => "mr-cluster"
    codec => "json"
}
}
```

Something pretty simple when i only use a file as output it works perfectly, logstash works.
The problem is when i wanna use elasticsearch as output, nothing works anymore (event file output) and i get this exception from elasticsearch. I've been searching on google for hours now and didn't find the solution.

Here is the exception :

```
[2014-05-21 09:18:35,060][WARN ][http.netty               ] [mr-node-elasticsearch] Caught     exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [id: 0x27d0ccce, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:44164 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9200]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:97)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:189)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:101)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Thank you for helping guys !

Answer (score 4):

when i got this error, i changed the port from 9200 to 9300. hope it works for you.

note: i am a beginner to elasticsearch.

probably this will NOT solve your problem, but it will probably help other begginers who searched for the same error message and was led to this page.

Comment: This error per-se means that netty is receiving garbage. It is failing to ascertain the http version in the request as a result. For example, this error can also occur when trying to speak https to an http port. OR in this scenario when communicating to the elasticsearch RESTful API port (default 9200) instead of the transport port (default 9300).

Comment: I am surprised but this worked for me.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The way you are configuring elasticsearch (using cluster name only) triggers multicast discovery of the cluster.  You can try configuring in the cluster directly to see if that works:

```
elasticsearch {
    host=>"ip_here"
    port=>9200
    protocol=>http
}
```

Also your cluster output said your cluster was in a "yellow" state, so you might want to figure out what's going on there -- you want it to be "green".

Answer (score 1):

The mistake that I made was in the configuration of the Elastic instances for unicast discovery.  I inadvertently added the port number 9200 to the configuration of the unicast hosts list.

Incorrect:

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["localhost.localdomain:9200"]
```

Correct:

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["localhost.localdomain"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing port to 9300 works just fine. But it's better to check the elastic search services. It could be down to. And indexing wouldn't take place hence this exception. I too am beginner to ELK stack.

Also if you don't wish to change ports then login to each elasticsearch nodes and run /etc/init.d/elasticsearch start